# How to display all images in a directory folder from database? Using entity framework lambda

Tags: c#, database, image, gridview

I uploaded many images through ajax file uploader, I save all the images in a directory only ( means its only 1 record in the database ). How do I display all the images in gridview from that directory?

this is my code on how i upload my images and store them in database by directory folder :

```
  protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        

        String pathdirectory = (Session["StoryPath"].ToString() + "/"); // selected item.

        EnsureDirectoriesExist(pathdirectory);

        String filepathImage = @"~/Story/" + pathdirectory;

        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filepathImage + e.FileName));


        Session["filepathImage"] = filepathImage;

    }

 protected void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        
          if (Session["filepathImage"] != null)
          {
              string filepathImage = Session["filepathImage"] as string; 
              act.ActivityID = Convert.ToInt32(dropListActivity.SelectedItem.Value);
              act.Title = txtStoryTitle.Text;

              act.FileURL = filepathImage;

              daoStory.Insert(act);
              daoStory.Save();  

             // Label1.Text = filepathImage;
           
           
          }
    }
```

Here is another code ( another web page on showing images to grid view) :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindStory();
        }
    }

    protected void BindStory()
    {
        gvStory.DataSource = daoStory.GetAll();
        gvStory.DataBind();
    }
```

I am using entity framework to retrieve the records from database and this is how I do this in my class file ( CRUD all in here ) :

```
   public IList<Model.story> GetAll(int listAct)
     {

         IList<Model.story> lstImages = context.stories.ToList();
         return lstImages.Where(c => c.ActivityID == listAct).Select(a => new Story() { a.FileURL }).ToList();

     }
```

I am new to this lambda expression and it gives me an error: Cannot initialize type with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable', am I doing this the correct way? I want to select fileURL (which is my database columns that store the folder directory of images I stored in) from story where activityID == listAct.

Comment: Story is not a collection or an anonymous type, it needs you to tell it which property to assign with `a.FileURL`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `Select` because you are returning Model.story already. Try to replace the `return` statement with:

```
return lstImages.Where(c => c.ActivityID == listAct).ToList();
```

As a note, use `Select` if you want to specifically return a collection of something. Your example has a wrong syntax on initializing values in your `new Story() { a.FileURL }`. Say we correct that syntax:

```
return lstImages.Where(c => c.ActivityID == listAct).Select(a => new Story() { FileURL = "SOMEURL" }).ToList();
```

This would mean that you are returning a list of `Story` from the list of `Model.story` satisfying your `Where` condition.

Comment: Thanks ! i understand what u meant ! Any idea on the images stuffs?

Comment: as long as the path of your images are valid, then it should be no problem.

Comment: but i not sure how grid view can work with images , because , grid view display all records in the database , but in my database , theres a column call FileURL , the URL is a folder that consists of many images  , is it possible for Grid View to display all images in that 1 record?

Comment: check this out. http://forums.asp.net/p/1687786/4450730.aspx/1?Re+Multiple+images+in+one+cell+in+gridview

Comment: sorry to trouble u but how do u write this : select fileurl from story where activity id == listAct? what does FileURL = "SOMEURL" means ? i could understand the rest i think

Comment: if you're talking about `new Story() { FileURL = "SOMEURL" }`, it just means that you are creating a new `Story` instance with an initial `FileURL` value of `"SOMEURL"`